# Use pyside6's QFileDialog.getSaveFileName to save a file and click the save button

Tags: python

When I use pyside6's `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName` to save a file and click the save button in the file box, my program gets stuck

```
self.save_file_fullname = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.v_obfuscate_tab, 'Save SystemVerilog/Verilog File', '../../../', 'Verilog Files (*.v; *.sv)')
print(self.save_file_fullname)
    if self.save_file_fullname:
        with open(self.save_file_fullname[0], "w") as f:
            f.write(self.v_obfuscate_tab.output_plainTextEdit.toPlainText())
```

I tried multi-threading and also the program died when I clicked the save button, clicked the save button and it didn't go back to the path and the main screen got stuck directly